# How to combine centers of circles and get x, y?

Tags: javascript

I need to place a little circle by center of bif circle not matter where click was made in borders of big circle.

Remark: coordinates of svg circle is relative by svg element (viewport), not parent div. So it means I can not operate with its redius, because I need to get coordinates of circle relative of div element as offsetX, offsetY.

I have tried this:

```js
let b = document.getElementById('extremum');

b.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let p = document.getElementById('point');
  if (p) {
    p.remove();
  }
  let x = e.offsetX;
  let y = e.offsetY;

  let point = document.createElement('div');
  point.style.width = "10px";
  point.style.height = "10px";
  point.style.background = "#000";
  point.style.top = y + "px";
  point.style.left = x + 'px';
  point.style.l = x + 'px';
  point.setAttribute("id", 'point');
  let c = document.getElementById('container');

  c.appendChild(point);
}, false);
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

circle {}

div {
  position: absolute;
}

#point {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="padding:0px; border:1px solid red;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2000 1000" width="2000px" height="1000px">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="10" fill="#4285f4" id="extremum" class="extremum"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qshaeb08/43/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qshaeb08/54/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getBBox` to get svg element.

Get top left and bottom right of svg box and then calculate the center of the box.

Finally, calculate the top left of point using the center of box and radius of point.

```js
let b = document.getElementById('extremum');
let cr = document.getElementById('changeRadius');

cr.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const valueString = document.getElementById('radius').value;
  if (!valueString) {
    return;
  }
  const value = Number(valueString);
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    return;
  }
  const circle = document.getElementById('extremum');
  circle.setAttribute("r", value);
  drawPoint();
});

b.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  drawPoint();
}, false);

function drawPoint() {
  let p = document.getElementById('point');
  if (p) {
    p.remove();
  }
  var svg = document.getElementById('extremum').getBBox();
  let topLeftX = svg.x;
  let topLeftY = svg.y;
  let bottomRightX = svg.x + svg.width;
  let bottomRightY = svg.y + svg.width;
  let centerX = (topLeftX + bottomRightX) / 2
  let centerY = (topLeftY + bottomRightY) / 2
  let point = document.createElement('div');
  let pointWidth = 10;
  let pointHeight = 10;
  point.style.width = pointWidth + "px";
  point.style.height = pointHeight + "px";
  point.style.background = "#000";
  let pointX = centerX - (pointWidth / 2);
  let pointY = centerY - (pointHeight / 2);
  point.style.top = pointX + "px";
  point.style.left = pointY + 'px'
  point.setAttribute("id", 'point');
  let c = document.getElementById('container');
  c.appendChild(point);
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

circle {}

div {
  position: absolute;
}

#point {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="padding:0px; border:1px solid red;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2000 1000" width="2000px" height="1000px">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="#4285f4" id="extremum" class="extremum"></circle>
  </svg>
  <input id="radius" />
  <button id="changeRadius">
  Change Radius
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: How to get offsetX, offsetY of blue circle after  place a black circle? Relative of #container?

Comment: And why do you devide on 4?

Comment: @MeganClerc, The divide by 4 was just calculation for the given radius of circle. (i.e. radius 10, which makes box width & height 20 and center is +5 px from top left. I have updated the code to be more generic and gave meaningful variable names so the calculations are self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `cx` and `cy` *c = center*, so you can get those.
You can use `b.cx.baseVal.value` for x and `b.cy.baseVal.value` for y.

If you set the width and height of the point with variables, then you can offset the position of the point you're adding by this amount too.

These are the essential modifications to your code:

```
  let pointWidth = 10;
  let pointHeight = 10;
  
  let x = b.cx.baseVal.value - pointWidth/2;
  let y = b.cy.baseVal.value - pointHeight/2;

  point.style.position = "absolute";
  point.style.width = pointWidth + "px";
  point.style.height = pointHeight + "px";
```

```js
let b = document.getElementById('extremum');

b.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let p = document.getElementById('point');
  if (p) {
    p.remove();
  }
 
  let pointWidth = 10;
  let pointHeight = 10;
  
  let x = b.cx.baseVal.value - pointWidth/2;
  let y = b.cy.baseVal.value - pointHeight/2;

  let point = document.createElement('div');
  point.style.position = "absolute";
  point.style.width = pointWidth + "px";
  point.style.height = pointHeight + "px";
  point.style.background = "#000";
  point.style.top = y + "px";
  point.style.left = x + 'px';
  point.style.l = x + 'px';
  point.setAttribute("id", 'point');
  let c = document.getElementById('container');

  c.appendChild(point);
}, false);
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

#point {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="padding:0px; border:1px solid red;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="400px" height="400px">
    <circle cx="80" cy="40" r="20" fill="#4285f4" id="extremum" class="extremum"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: He can use cx,xy because these coordinates are relative to SVG element, not parent container block. We need to get relative coordinates of blue cemter circle, offsetX, offsetY.